# Proper htaccess 301 to prevent duplicate hostname issues?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, hostname

I want to make sure there are no duplicate hostname issues and Google Analytics has suggested there are.

So, I want to make sure my home page is always www.example.com and not example.com or I suppose http://www.example.com

How is this done safely?

I found one example, but as I am not a guru at this sort of thing, figured I needed a second opinion or two:

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$ 
 RewriteRule .? http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The more explanation the better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex in `RewriteCond` looks suspect since it makes whole hostname optional. You can have this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```